# PIC Header Files

Tags: pic, mplab

I have trouble building my pic project. I used

```
#include "p18f8722.inc"
```

at the beginning of my .asm file but it gives the following error:

> can't open include file "p18f8722.inc": No such file or directory

How can I deal with this issue?

Comment: Are you using MPLAB X? When creating a new project you would have been prompted to choose an assembler, setting up the path to the headers in the MPLABX directory.